# Effective way to loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to find an optimal way to execute the below loop statement

I have the below code that works just fine where in I check for length of a column and perform actions accordingly. However I am unable to optimise the code but have to create this long if statements

Given below is the code I have:

```
    if len(name) == 1:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
    elif len(name) == 2:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
    elif len(name) == 3:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
    elif len(name) == 4:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
        table.cell(4, 0).text = str(type_4_1)
        table.cell(4, 1).text = str(type_4_2)
        table.cell(4, 2).text = str(type_4_3)
        table.cell(4, 3).text = str(type_4_4)
    elif len(name) == 5:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
        table.cell(4, 0).text = str(type_4_1)
        table.cell(4, 1).text = str(type_4_2)
        table.cell(4, 2).text = str(type_4_3)
        table.cell(4, 3).text = str(type_4_4)
        table.cell(5, 0).text = str(type_5_1)
        table.cell(5, 1).text = str(type_5_2)
        table.cell(5, 2).text = str(type_5_3)
        table.cell(5, 3).text = str(type_5_4)
    elif len(name) == 6:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
        table.cell(4, 0).text = str(type_4_1)
        table.cell(4, 1).text = str(type_4_2)
        table.cell(4, 2).text = str(type_4_3)
        table.cell(4, 3).text = str(type_4_4)
        table.cell(5, 0).text = str(type_5_1)
        table.cell(5, 1).text = str(type_5_2)
        table.cell(5, 2).text = str(type_5_3)
        table.cell(5, 3).text = str(type_5_4)
        table.cell(6, 0).text = str(type_6_1)
        table.cell(6, 1).text = str(type_6_2)
        table.cell(6, 2).text = str(type_6_3)
        table.cell(6, 3).text = str(type_6_4)
    elif len(name) == 7:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
        table.cell(4, 0).text = str(type_4_1)
        table.cell(4, 1).text = str(type_4_2)
        table.cell(4, 2).text = str(type_4_3)
        table.cell(4, 3).text = str(type_4_4)
        table.cell(5, 0).text = str(type_5_1)
        table.cell(5, 1).text = str(type_5_2)
        table.cell(5, 2).text = str(type_5_3)
        table.cell(5, 3).text = str(type_5_4)
        table.cell(6, 0).text = str(type_6_1)
        table.cell(6, 1).text = str(type_6_2)
        table.cell(6, 2).text = str(type_6_3)
        table.cell(6, 3).text = str(type_6_4)
        table.cell(7, 0).text = str(type_7_1)
        table.cell(7, 1).text = str(type_7_2)
        table.cell(7, 2).text = str(type_7_3)
        table.cell(7, 3).text = str(type_7_4)
    elif len(name) == 8:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
        table.cell(4, 0).text = str(type_4_1)
        table.cell(4, 1).text = str(type_4_2)
        table.cell(4, 2).text = str(type_4_3)
        table.cell(4, 3).text = str(type_4_4)
        table.cell(5, 0).text = str(type_5_1)
        table.cell(5, 1).text = str(type_5_2)
        table.cell(5, 2).text = str(type_5_3)
        table.cell(5, 3).text = str(type_5_4)
        table.cell(6, 0).text = str(type_6_1)
        table.cell(6, 1).text = str(type_6_2)
        table.cell(6, 2).text = str(type_6_3)
        table.cell(6, 3).text = str(type_6_4)
        table.cell(7, 0).text = str(type_7_1)
        table.cell(7, 1).text = str(type_7_2)
        table.cell(7, 2).text = str(type_7_3)
        table.cell(7, 3).text = str(type_7_4)
        table.cell(8, 0).text = str(type_8_1)
        table.cell(8, 1).text = str(type_8_2)
        table.cell(8, 2).text = str(type_8_3)
        table.cell(8, 3).text = str(type_8_4)
    elif len(name) == 9:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
        table.cell(4, 0).text = str(type_4_1)
        table.cell(4, 1).text = str(type_4_2)
        table.cell(4, 2).text = str(type_4_3)
        table.cell(4, 3).text = str(type_4_4)
        table.cell(5, 0).text = str(type_5_1)
        table.cell(5, 1).text = str(type_5_2)
        table.cell(5, 2).text = str(type_5_3)
        table.cell(5, 3).text = str(type_5_4)
        table.cell(6, 0).text = str(type_6_1)
        table.cell(6, 1).text = str(type_6_2)
        table.cell(6, 2).text = str(type_6_3)
        table.cell(6, 3).text = str(type_6_4)
        table.cell(7, 0).text = str(type_7_1)
        table.cell(7, 1).text = str(type_7_2)
        table.cell(7, 2).text = str(type_7_3)
        table.cell(7, 3).text = str(type_7_4)
        table.cell(8, 0).text = str(type_8_1)
        table.cell(8, 1).text = str(type_8_2)
        table.cell(8, 2).text = str(type_8_3)
        table.cell(8, 3).text = str(type_8_4)
        table.cell(9, 0).text = str(type_9_1)
        table.cell(9, 1).text = str(type_9_2)
        table.cell(9, 2).text = str(type_9_3)
        table.cell(9, 3).text = str(type_9_4)
    elif len(name) == 10:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
        table.cell(4, 0).text = str(type_4_1)
        table.cell(4, 1).text = str(type_4_2)
        table.cell(4, 2).text = str(type_4_3)
        table.cell(4, 3).text = str(type_4_4)
        table.cell(5, 0).text = str(type_5_1)
        table.cell(5, 1).text = str(type_5_2)
        table.cell(5, 2).text = str(type_5_3)
        table.cell(5, 3).text = str(type_5_4)
        table.cell(6, 0).text = str(type_6_1)
        table.cell(6, 1).text = str(type_6_2)
        table.cell(6, 2).text = str(type_6_3)
        table.cell(6, 3).text = str(type_6_4)
        table.cell(7, 0).text = str(type_7_1)
        table.cell(7, 1).text = str(type_7_2)
        table.cell(7, 2).text = str(type_7_3)
        table.cell(7, 3).text = str(type_7_4)
        table.cell(8, 0).text = str(type_8_1)
        table.cell(8, 1).text = str(type_8_2)
        table.cell(8, 2).text = str(type_8_3)
        table.cell(8, 3).text = str(type_8_4)
        table.cell(9, 0).text = str(type_9_1)
        table.cell(9, 1).text = str(type_9_2)
        table.cell(9, 2).text = str(type_9_3)
        table.cell(9, 3).text = str(type_9_4)
        table.cell(10, 0).text = str(type_10_1)
        table.cell(10, 1).text = str(type_10_2)
        table.cell(10, 2).text = str(type_10_3)
        table.cell(10, 3).text = str(type_10_4)
    elif len(name) == 11:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
        table.cell(4, 0).text = str(type_4_1)
        table.cell(4, 1).text = str(type_4_2)
        table.cell(4, 2).text = str(type_4_3)
        table.cell(4, 3).text = str(type_4_4)
        table.cell(5, 0).text = str(type_5_1)
        table.cell(5, 1).text = str(type_5_2)
        table.cell(5, 2).text = str(type_5_3)
        table.cell(5, 3).text = str(type_5_4)
        table.cell(6, 0).text = str(type_6_1)
        table.cell(6, 1).text = str(type_6_2)
        table.cell(6, 2).text = str(type_6_3)
        table.cell(6, 3).text = str(type_6_4)
        table.cell(7, 0).text = str(type_7_1)
        table.cell(7, 1).text = str(type_7_2)
        table.cell(7, 2).text = str(type_7_3)
        table.cell(7, 3).text = str(type_7_4)
        table.cell(8, 0).text = str(type_8_1)
        table.cell(8, 1).text = str(type_8_2)
        table.cell(8, 2).text = str(type_8_3)
        table.cell(8, 3).text = str(type_8_4)
        table.cell(9, 0).text = str(type_9_1)
        table.cell(9, 1).text = str(type_9_2)
        table.cell(9, 2).text = str(type_9_3)
        table.cell(9, 3).text = str(type_9_4)
        table.cell(10, 0).text = str(type_10_1)
        table.cell(10, 1).text = str(type_10_2)
        table.cell(10, 2).text = str(type_10_3)
        table.cell(10, 3).text = str(type_10_4)
        table.cell(11, 0).text = str(type_11_1)
        table.cell(11, 1).text = str(type_11_2)
        table.cell(11, 2).text = str(type_11_3)
        table.cell(11, 3).text = str(type_11_4)
    elif len(name) == 12:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
        table.cell(4, 0).text = str(type_4_1)
        table.cell(4, 1).text = str(type_4_2)
        table.cell(4, 2).text = str(type_4_3)
        table.cell(4, 3).text = str(type_4_4)
        table.cell(5, 0).text = str(type_5_1)
        table.cell(5, 1).text = str(type_5_2)
        table.cell(5, 2).text = str(type_5_3)
        table.cell(5, 3).text = str(type_5_4)
        table.cell(6, 0).text = str(type_6_1)
        table.cell(6, 1).text = str(type_6_2)
        table.cell(6, 2).text = str(type_6_3)
        table.cell(6, 3).text = str(type_6_4)
        table.cell(7, 0).text = str(type_7_1)
        table.cell(7, 1).text = str(type_7_2)
        table.cell(7, 2).text = str(type_7_3)
        table.cell(7, 3).text = str(type_7_4)
        table.cell(8, 0).text = str(type_8_1)
        table.cell(8, 1).text = str(type_8_2)
        table.cell(8, 2).text = str(type_8_3)
        table.cell(8, 3).text = str(type_8_4)
        table.cell(9, 0).text = str(type_9_1)
        table.cell(9, 1).text = str(type_9_2)
        table.cell(9, 2).text = str(type_9_3)
        table.cell(9, 3).text = str(type_9_4)
        table.cell(10, 0).text = str(type_10_1)
        table.cell(10, 1).text = str(type_10_2)
        table.cell(10, 2).text = str(type_10_3)
        table.cell(10, 3).text = str(type_10_4)
        table.cell(11, 0).text = str(type_11_1)
        table.cell(11, 1).text = str(type_11_2)
        table.cell(11, 2).text = str(type_11_3)
        table.cell(11, 3).text = str(type_11_4)
        table.cell(12, 0).text = str(type_12_1)
        table.cell(12, 1).text = str(type_12_2)
        table.cell(12, 2).text = str(type_12_3)
        table.cell(12, 3).text = str(type_12_4)
    elif len(name) == 13:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
        table.cell(4, 0).text = str(type_4_1)
        table.cell(4, 1).text = str(type_4_2)
        table.cell(4, 2).text = str(type_4_3)
        table.cell(4, 3).text = str(type_4_4)
        table.cell(5, 0).text = str(type_5_1)
        table.cell(5, 1).text = str(type_5_2)
        table.cell(5, 2).text = str(type_5_3)
        table.cell(5, 3).text = str(type_5_4)
        table.cell(6, 0).text = str(type_6_1)
        table.cell(6, 1).text = str(type_6_2)
        table.cell(6, 2).text = str(type_6_3)
        table.cell(6, 3).text = str(type_6_4)
        table.cell(7, 0).text = str(type_7_1)
        table.cell(7, 1).text = str(type_7_2)
        table.cell(7, 2).text = str(type_7_3)
        table.cell(7, 3).text = str(type_7_4)
        table.cell(8, 0).text = str(type_8_1)
        table.cell(8, 1).text = str(type_8_2)
        table.cell(8, 2).text = str(type_8_3)
        table.cell(8, 3).text = str(type_8_4)
        table.cell(9, 0).text = str(type_9_1)
        table.cell(9, 1).text = str(type_9_2)
        table.cell(9, 2).text = str(type_9_3)
        table.cell(9, 3).text = str(type_9_4)
        table.cell(10, 0).text = str(type_10_1)
        table.cell(10, 1).text = str(type_10_2)
        table.cell(10, 2).text = str(type_10_3)
        table.cell(10, 3).text = str(type_10_4)
        table.cell(11, 0).text = str(type_11_1)
        table.cell(11, 1).text = str(type_11_2)
        table.cell(11, 2).text = str(type_11_3)
        table.cell(11, 3).text = str(type_11_4)
        table.cell(12, 0).text = str(type_12_1)
        table.cell(12, 1).text = str(type_12_2)
        table.cell(12, 2).text = str(type_12_3)
        table.cell(12, 3).text = str(type_12_4)
        table.cell(13, 0).text = str(type_13_1)
        table.cell(13, 1).text = str(type_13_2)
        table.cell(13, 2).text = str(type_13_3)
        table.cell(13, 3).text = str(type_13_4)
    elif len(name) == 14:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
        table.cell(4, 0).text = str(type_4_1)
        table.cell(4, 1).text = str(type_4_2)
        table.cell(4, 2).text = str(type_4_3)
        table.cell(4, 3).text = str(type_4_4)
        table.cell(5, 0).text = str(type_5_1)
        table.cell(5, 1).text = str(type_5_2)
        table.cell(5, 2).text = str(type_5_3)
        table.cell(5, 3).text = str(type_5_4)
        table.cell(6, 0).text = str(type_6_1)
        table.cell(6, 1).text = str(type_6_2)
        table.cell(6, 2).text = str(type_6_3)
        table.cell(6, 3).text = str(type_6_4)
        table.cell(7, 0).text = str(type_7_1)
        table.cell(7, 1).text = str(type_7_2)
        table.cell(7, 2).text = str(type_7_3)
        table.cell(7, 3).text = str(type_7_4)
        table.cell(8, 0).text = str(type_8_1)
        table.cell(8, 1).text = str(type_8_2)
        table.cell(8, 2).text = str(type_8_3)
        table.cell(8, 3).text = str(type_8_4)
        table.cell(9, 0).text = str(type_9_1)
        table.cell(9, 1).text = str(type_9_2)
        table.cell(9, 2).text = str(type_9_3)
        table.cell(9, 3).text = str(type_9_4)
        table.cell(10, 0).text = str(type_10_1)
        table.cell(10, 1).text = str(type_10_2)
        table.cell(10, 2).text = str(type_10_3)
        table.cell(10, 3).text = str(type_10_4)
        table.cell(11, 0).text = str(type_11_1)
        table.cell(11, 1).text = str(type_11_2)
        table.cell(11, 2).text = str(type_11_3)
        table.cell(11, 3).text = str(type_11_4)
        table.cell(12, 0).text = str(type_12_1)
        table.cell(12, 1).text = str(type_12_2)
        table.cell(12, 2).text = str(type_12_3)
        table.cell(12, 3).text = str(type_12_4)
        table.cell(13, 0).text = str(type_13_1)
        table.cell(13, 1).text = str(type_13_2)
        table.cell(13, 2).text = str(type_13_3)
        table.cell(13, 3).text = str(type_13_4)
        table.cell(14, 0).text = str(type_14_1)
        table.cell(14, 1).text = str(type_14_2)
        table.cell(14, 2).text = str(type_14_3)
        table.cell(14, 3).text = str(type_14_4)
```

Comment: Think about replacing `if len(name) == 1:` with `if len(name) >= 1:` (not just for 1, but for all the other numbers as well). Then for each larger number you will only have to add the new cells.

Comment: What is `type_1_1`?

Comment: @user5173426 its a variable that is assigned a value

Comment: You need a dynamic way to get the `type_i_j` with every i, j. You can try to build the string `type_{0}_{1}.format(i, j)`, then get the variable from the `local()` dict.

Comment: For the loop, it looks like this: `for i in range(len(name)): for j in range(4): table.cell(i, j).text = local().get('type_{0}_{1}'.format(i, j + 1)`.

Comment: @scottmartin you could write a method that would take the length, table and type as a parameter and do a foor loop inside it. I just posted an answer with that approach

Comment: You should not have stored your values in so many oddly named variables in the first place.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how this question is anything other than "how do I create a loop in Python?".

Answer (score 1):

It appears that all your values build on each other. That is, the work done for length N is equal to the work done for length N-1, plus one more bit of work. With that in mind, consider making your `if` statements non-exclusive, like so:

```
    if len(name) >= 1:
        table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
        table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
        table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
        table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)

    # Note: NOT elif, just if
    if len(name) >= 2:
        table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
        table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
        table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
        table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)

    if len(name) == 3:
        table.cell(3, 0).text = str(type_3_1)
        table.cell(3, 1).text = str(type_3_2)
        table.cell(3, 2).text = str(type_3_3)
        table.cell(3, 3).text = str(type_3_4)
```

Now there is a nice repeating pattern. The next problem is that the various `type_X_Y` variables are stored as separate names instead of using a list or dictionary. There are a couple of hacky things that could be done, but let's just ignore that until you give more data. Instead, let's create a function that sets one row of table cell data:

```
def set_table_row(table, rownum, *values):
    assert len(values) == 4, "4 values are required per row"

    for col, value in enumerate(values):
        table.cell(rownum, col) = str(value)
```

Now you can collapse the 4 statements in each block into a single helper-function call:

```
    if len(name) >= 1:
        set_table_row(table, 1, type_1_1, type_1_2, type_1_3, type_1_4)
    if len(name) >= 2:
        set_table_row(table, 2, type_2_1, type_2_2, type_2_3, type_2_4)
    if len(name) == 3:
        set_table_row(table, 3, type_3_1, type_3_2, type_3_3, type_3_4)
```

This might be enough for you. If not, you'll need to provide more information about what the various `type_X_Y` values are: are they global or local variables, properties on an object, values extracted from a tuple?

Comment: `assert` should not be used for control flow, as assertions can be turned off.

Comment: Aside from appealing to `locals()`, this seems to be the most reasonable solution.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the objection to `assert` is. I'm not doing control flow, I'm requiring a certain number of arguments and reminding the coder of that requirement.

Comment: That requirement and reminder may not show up. `assert` is for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a multi-dimensional array for values or a dictionary instead of custom variables, but you can do it like this:

```
for x in range(len(name)):
    table.cell(x, 0).text = str(locals()["type_" + x + "_1"])
    table.cell(x, 1).text = str(locals()["type_" + x + "_2"])
    table.cell(x, 2).text = str(locals()["type_" + x + "_3"])
    table.cell(x, 3).text = str(locals()["type_" + x + "_4"])
```

Or another loop:

```
for i in range(len(name)):
    for j in range(4):
        table.cell(i, j).text = str(locals()["type_" + i + "_" + j])
```

Multidimensional array could be done like this:

```
types = [[]]
types[0][0] = "foo"
types[0][1] = "bar"
# ...
types[1][0] = ".."

for i in range(len(name)):
    for j in range(4):
        table.cell(i, j).text = types[i][j]
```

Comment: Using `locals()` is a terrible solution that just encourages a pile of individual variables and should not be recommended.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Of course not, that's why I recommend a multi-dimensional array or dictionary. But given the choice of this many local variables, using `locals()` is by far the most maintainable solution.

Comment: Luckily, nobody recommended `eval()` so far :)

Comment: Your recommendation of a real solution is a fragment of a sentence, while your `locals()` solution is fully expressed in two different ways. And that's not a maintainable solution at all; that's why it "of course" should not be recommended in the first place. This answer is harmful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterators:

```
from itertools import cycle, count

types_ = ((k, v) for k, v in dict(locals()).items() if k.startswith('type_'))
types = [type for _, type in sorted(types_)]

### Alternatively you can define the list with types manually
### types = [type_1_1, type_1_2, type_1_3, type_1_4...]

def func(name):
    # assert len(name) <= len(types)
    r = (i for i in count(start=1) for _ in range(4))
    c = cycle(range(4))
    t = iter(types)

    for _ in range(len(name) * 4):
        table.cell(next(r), next(c)).text = str(next(t))
```

### Example:

```
types = [f'type_{i}_{j}' for i in range(1, 100) for j in range(1, 5)]
# ['type_1_1', 'type_1_2', 'type_1_3', 'type_1_4', 'type_2_1', 'type_2_2', 'type_2_3', 'type_2_4'...]

def func(name):
    r = (i for i in count(start=1) for _ in range(4))
    c = cycle(range(4))
    t = iter(types)

    for _ in range(len(name) * 4):
        print(f'table.cell({next(r)}, {next(c)}).text = str({next(t)})')

func('AB')
```

#### Output:

```
table.cell(1, 0).text = str(type_1_1)
table.cell(1, 1).text = str(type_1_2)
table.cell(1, 2).text = str(type_1_3)
table.cell(1, 3).text = str(type_1_4)
table.cell(2, 0).text = str(type_2_1)
table.cell(2, 1).text = str(type_2_2)
table.cell(2, 2).text = str(type_2_3)
table.cell(2, 3).text = str(type_2_4)
```